# spring session initialization error

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-session

I am trying to implement Spring Session following this tutorial
[Spring HttpSession Tutorial](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/httpsession.html)

But I am running into an initialization error when I start up the application.

> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'springSessionRepositoryFilter' defined in class org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 1 of type [javax.servlet.ServletContext]: : No qualifying bean of type [javax.servlet.ServletContext] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.servlet.ServletContext] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}

I may be wrong, but it looks like there is no implementation of ServletContext that is annotated, should I add *any additional dependencies* to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To anyone who encounter this issue:
I switched to the snapshot version 1.1.0 of spring security and the issue was gone.
If you are using maven, add the spring snapshot repository in the pom.
[This tutorial helped](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html5/guides/security.html)

Answer (score 0):

Although you can play with spring modules versions and solve it, you may cause countless other issues due to incompatible spring versions.
Instead you can use a solution using: ServletContextExposure and FactoryBean

I used that on a legacy project that uses spring 3 with XML configuration:

```
 public class ServletContextExposure implements ServletContextAware, FactoryBean<ServletContext> {

    private ServletContext servletContext;

    @Override
    public ServletContext getObject() {
        return this.servletContext;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return ServletContext.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
        this.servletContext = servletContext;
    }
}
```

If your'e using XML configuration so just add it to your spring XML:

```
    <bean id= "servletContextExposure"  class="com.borderfree.boot.ServletContextExposure"/>
```